# Why i am getting IOException while SAX parsing

Tags: android

While retrieving the value i am not able to retrieve the values. Why i am getting IOexcetion in the below given code ? There is something wrong with the handler but i am not able to figure it out.

```
public SitesList opCodeRequest(String code)
    {
        SitesList objsitelist =null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet method= new HttpGet();
            method.setURI(new URI(AppConstatnt.OPCODE_URL+code));

            HttpResponse response=client.execute(method);           
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();         
            InputStream stream=entity.getContent();

            Log.e("b4 execute in login","aditya");

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 
            OPCodeHandler myopcodeHandler = new OPCodeHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myopcodeHandler); 

            xr.parse(new InputSource(stream)); 
            objsitelist = myopcodeHandler.getSiteList();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//error
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objsitelist;


    }
```

Handler

```
public class OPCodeHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = "";
    SitesList siteobject;

    public SitesList getSiteList() {
        return siteobject;
    }

    public void setSiteList(SitesList objsite) {
        siteobject = objsite;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = true;
        currentValue = "";
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("opcode")) {
            siteobject = new SitesList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        currentElement = false;
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tsip")) {
            siteobject.setTsip(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("ssip")) {
            siteobject.setSsip(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("brand")) {
            siteobject.setBrand(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("balance")) {
            siteobject.setBalance(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("rates")) {
            siteobject.setRates(currentValue);
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("domain")) {
            siteobject.setDomain(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("operator")) {
            siteobject.setOperator(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("active")) {
            siteobject.setActive(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("opcode")) {
            setSiteList(siteobject);
        }

    }

}
```

Activity where i am retrieving the value.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SitesList result) 
        {
            if(this.objprogress.isShowing())
            {
                this.objprogress.dismiss();
            }

            tsip = result.getTsip();
            ssip = result.getSsip();
            brand = result.getBrand(); 
            balance = result.getBalance();
            rates = result.getRates();
            domain = result.getDomain();
            operator = result.getOperator();
            active = result.getActive();
        }
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sample.test.SampleAppActivity$Communicator.onPostExecute(SampleAppActivity.java:161)
at com.sample.test.SampleAppActivity$Communicator.onPostExecute(SampleAppActivity.java:1)

at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you also post your logCat entry?

Comment: I have posted the logcat entry.

Answer (score 0):

You get a nullpointer Exception. That mean a variable or something is null where it shouldn't be. I think first of all, you should try to inizialise all of you variables correct.

for example:

```
SitesList objsitelist =null;
```

should be inizialised like:

```
SitesList objsitelist =new SitesList();
```

Reply if you have done this and it still won't work.

Comment: can you please say which code is on line 161 of the "SampleAppActivity" or post the whole activity